# QGIS attribute table: round values but don't change the data

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In my attribute table of a vector layer I have the following field with the decimal data.

[image]

I would like that QGIS shows me only the first 2 decimal positions in the Attribute table, but I do NOT want QGIS to actually change the data.
Just to show me the data a bit nicer.

Is that possible? Is there a function I'm not seeing?

I'm using QGIS 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in an attribute table in print layout then you can use the Expression editor (Epsilon button by the new row) and use the `round` function

```
round("no2", 2)
```

Where "no2" is the name of the attribute you would like to use.

Comment: how do I get access to the attribute table in the print layout? In the "project view" something like that is not possible?

Comment: There is a button down the LHS of the screen (by default) that adds an attribute table to your print out.

Comment: you mean the two Buttons where you can switch between the 'table view' and the 'form view'?